# Does PowerShell have a clean way of validating a path to a file to be created?

Tags: powershell, validation

In Python there are simple one liners that can take a path like `C:\somefolder\somesubfolder\file.csv`, grab the `C:\somefolder\somesubfolder\` part, if it exists, and tell you if it's valid. I have to account for a user potentially passing in an absolute path, a relative path, or no path at all and the file just writing to the same directory. Some potential user input:

- `..\an_invalid_folder\something.csv`
- `C:\`
- `an invalid folder\something.csv`
- `something.csv`
- `some_absolute_path\something.csv`

In PowerShell I found this surprisingly cumbersome. I found things like Split-Path have strange behaviors - Ex: if you pass only `C:\` and then run split path with the leaf option it will tell you `C:\` is the leaf. Now, I understand why they do that but it makes solving the above a bit ugly. Below is what I came up with - does PowerShell not have something like the `os.path` library that more cleanly handles all these situations?

```
$ParentPath = $(Split-Path -Path $OutputFilePath -Parent)
if ($ParentPath -ne "") {
  if (-not $(Test-Path -PathType Container $ParentPath)) {
    Write-Error "The path you provided for $($OutputFilePath) is not valid." -ErrorAction Stop
  }
}

if (Test-Path $(Split-Path -Path $OutputFilePath -Leaf) -PathType Container) {
  Write-Error "You must provide a filename as part of the path. It looks like you only provided a folder in $($OutputFilePath)!" -ErrorAction Stop
}

Try { [io.file]::OpenWrite($outfile).close() }
Catch { Write-Error "It looks like you may not have permissions to $($OutputFilePath). We tried to open a file object there and the test failed." -ErrorAction Stop }
```

Comment: Want a one-liner? `(@(Split-Path $OutputFilePath -Parent |Where-Object {$_} |Test-Path)-eq$false).Count-eq0` :-D

Comment: [System.IO.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0)

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help Resolve-Path` and the properties it returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is **undoubtedly room for improvement in PowerShell's `*-Path` cmdlets**, notably **with respect to allowing the specified paths to (partially) *not exist* (yet)** - for example, see the [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path)-related [GitHub proposal #2993](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2993).
- While direct use of the methods of the static .NET [`System.IO.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path) class offers a way around that, a notable - and [unavoidable](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3428) - pitfall is **that .NET's current directory usually differs from PowerShell's**, which means:

  - You should generally **always pass *full* paths to .NET methods** (with *existing* paths, passing a path to `Convert-Path` first can ensure that). In your case, the  `[io.file]::OpenWrite()` call may either fail or create the file *elsewhere* if given a *relative* (or file-name-only) path.

    - Additionally, .NET knows nothing of *PowerShell-specific drives* (created with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)), so paths based on such drives must be converted to *file-system-native* paths - again, `Convert-Path` does that.
    - To get PowerShell's current directory as a native file-system path, use `$PWD.ProviderPath` (or, if there's a chance that the current location is that of a provider *other* than the file-system, such as the *registry* on Windows: `(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath`).
  - Similarly, **`[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath()` specifically resolves a relative path relative to *.NET's* current directory, so it generally won't work as expected** (unless you explicitly *synchronize* the current directories first, with `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD.ProviderPath`).

    - In ***PowerShell (Core) 7+ only*,** you can work around the problem with the optional (.NET Core-only) 2nd parameter that allows passing in a *reference* directory:

      - `[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('foo', $PWD.ProviderPath)`

---

Here's a **slightly simpler solution** than yours, which partly relies on the underlying .NET exceptions to provide meaningful error messages:

```
try { 
  $null = New-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Type File $OutputFilePath
} catch { 
  Throw "`"$OutputFilePath`" is not a valid -OutFilePath argument: " + $(
    if (Test-Path -PathType Container -LiteralPath $OutputFilePath) { 
      "Please specify a path to a *file*, not just a directory." 
    } else  {
      $_.Exception.Message
    }
  )
}

# Note: As with your approach, file $OutFilePath now exists as an empty, 
#       in a closed state.
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that path validation methods that previously worked in PS 5.1 don't work in pwsh.  See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20847